# Google cast sdk v3 notification missing for Android Oreo

Tags: android, google-cast

Using appcompat and mediarouter version 26.0.2 with play-services-cast-framework version 11.2.2, the default cast notification isn't showing on android Oreo devices (works fine for pre Oreo devices). This seems related to the sdk not requesting a channel for his notification.

This is my CastOptionsProvider file:

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

@Override
public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context appContext) {
    List<String> buttonActions = new ArrayList<>();
    buttonActions.add(MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_REWIND);
    buttonActions.add(MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK);
    buttonActions.add(MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_FORWARD);
    buttonActions.add(MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_STOP_CASTING);
    int[] compatButtonActionsIndicies = new int[]{0, 1};
    NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
            .setActions(buttonActions, compatButtonActionsIndicies)
            .setSkipStepMs(30 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
            .setTargetActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
            .build();
    CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
            .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
            .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
            .setImagePicker(new PlayImagePicker())
            .build();

    return new CastOptions.Builder().setReceiverApplicationId(appContext.getString(R.string.CHROMECAST_APP))
                .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I didn't see any way to provide a notification channel, but maybe I'm missing something. Is someone already found a solution to this issue ?

Comment: I noticed the same thing. The Cast SDK is not yet ready for Oreo. In the meantime I set my targetSdkVersion to 25 but I keep using compileSdkVersion 26.

Comment: Google Issue Tracker link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67251634

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well. Bumping targetSdkVersion down to 25 as recommended by @BladeCoder seems to be a temporary solution.

Comment: with reference to google bug tracker it has been fixed for more update you can check here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67251634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the bug tracker ticket, "This issue is fixed internally and fix will be available in future releases."... So wait and see !